# Finding limit of a sequence $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+a_{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

For the sequence,

$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+a_{n}}\; \forall n \geq 1$ ,

**EDIT:** $a_{1}=1$

I tried to find the monotonicity by converting it into

$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}\ \implies\ f'(x)=-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2} < 0\ \forall\ x\geq 1 $

So the sequence is monotonically decreasing. But fiding the limit of $f(x)$ resulted in

$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\infty} = \frac{1}{\infty} = 0$

Is my assumption in converting the $a_{n+1}$ t0 $f(x)$ is incorrect. How can I find whether the sequence converges?.

**EDIT2:** I understand that $f(x)$ formulation is incorrect. How can I prove the sequence is monotonic and find its limit?.

Comment: What is. the value of $a_1$?

Comment: You don't know if $x$ goes to infinity, that is your mistake. $x$ is pretty much $a_n$

Comment: You haven't proven that the sequence is monotonic. You have proven that $f(x)$ is monotonic, while you would have to prove $f(x)<x$.

Comment: converting $a_n$ to $f(n)$ and extending it to $f(x)$ (if possible and convenient) is fine but $f(n) \ne \frac 1 {1 + n}$.

Comment: By now you have probably realized that $a_n = \frac {F_n}{F_{n+1}}$ where $F_i$ are the fibonocci numbers.  It's not particular relevant or helpful in solving this but it is worth noting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your sequence is not monotonic, so if there is a limit, the sequence is oscillating around the limit: the even numbered terms are monotonically increasing and the odd ones are monotonically decreasing.

**Sketch of the proof:**

First prove by induction that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is positive and that $a_n\leq 1,\,\forall n\in\mathbb N$. Then show that $\{a_{2k}\},\,k=1,2,..$ is monotonically increasing and that $\{a_{2k+1}\},\,k=0,1,2,..$ is monotonically decreasing (again by induction). Because both subsequences are bounded and monotonic, they are convergent to $0\leq L_1\leq 1$ and $0\leq L_2\leq 1$, respectively. Finally you show that both limits are equal from the equation 
$$L_i=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+L_i}},\,i=1,2\Rightarrow L_i=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\in [0,1]$$

Answer (score 2):

If you have already proved that the sequence has a limit,
you can find the limit $L$ from the recurrence equation:

$L = \frac{1}{L+1}$

This gives two roots but one is negative so that one cannot be the limit
(since all members of the sequence are obviously positive).

So:

$L = \frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}$